# Problem when user has multi roles in Blazor Webassembly authentication and authorisation?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor-webassembly, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a Blazor Webassembly solution, when I login with user (has multi roles), login action show error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role
         at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
         at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
         at REMO.Server.Controllers.AuthController.CurrentUserInfo() in D:\REMO\REMO\Server\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 87
         at lambda_method29(Closure , Object , Object[] )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean&
isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Following my **Custom Authentication Provider**:

```cs
public class CustomStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
        private readonly IAuthService api;
    private CurrentUser _currentUser;
    public CustomStateProvider(IAuthService api)
    {
        this.api = api;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        try
        {
                var userInfo = await GetCurrentUser();
                var roleClaims = identity.FindAll(identity.RoleClaimType);
                if (userInfo.IsAuthenticated)
                
                {
                var claims = new[] 
                { 
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _currentUser.UserName)
                }
                .Concat(_currentUser.Claims.Select(c => new Claim(c.Key, c.Value)));
                    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Server authentication");
                }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request failed:" + ex.ToString());
        }

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
...
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
...
```

The problem seems to be the presence of multiple roles for an identity.
In case of an identity with only one role the problem doesn't arise.

Comment: Check in login if you already have the claim with the same name

Comment: Think you,...If I login with user have one role no problems!...

Comment: Hi zekad, if the answer resolves your problem, please mark it as the corrected answer, in order to be helpful for the future user.

Comment: Hi Nicola, think you very much for this answer,your answer is correct and logic, but I can't set the right code for now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the construction of the **role** claim key.
This key, in case of multiple role, has to be an *array*.
You cannot have multiple "role" key in your JWT token.

I think you've used the code from [Mukesh](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/authentication-in-blazor-webassembly/) and is a good starting point, but if you read the comment, the last one explain a problem like yours.

So you need to modify the line

```cs
.Concat(_currentUser.Claims.Select(c => new Claim(c.Key, c.Value)));
```

extracting via LINQ all the claims that **aren't** of type *role* and add them to the `claims` array.
Now you need to create an array of all claims of type *role* (I think they come from your API) and add a single *role* claim entry of array type.

After that modification I think it should work.

The resulting decoded JWT token should have the form:

```json
{
   "sub": "nbiada",
   "jti": "123...",
   "role" : [
      "User",
      "Admin"
   ],
   "exp": 12345467,
...
}
```

**Note**:
I've shorten the `role` key, in your implementation should be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`

Answer (score 0):

As [Nicola Biada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11109967/nicola-biada) said,Your problem is the construction of the role claim key.
I implement [Mukesh](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/authentication-in-blazor-webassembly/) Sample and just modify CurrentUserInfo action in AuthController for send role claims as a array.
This is my action

```
public CurrentUser CurrentUserInfo()
{
    var roles = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(roles);
    var claims = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type != ClaimTypes.Role).ToDictionary(c => c.Type, c => c.Value);
    claims.Add(ClaimTypes.Role, json);
    return new CurrentUser
    {
        IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
        UserName = User.Identity.Name,
        Claims = claims
    };
}
```

Then in client side i return to the previous state. for that i change GetAuthenticationStateAsync in CustomStateProvider.

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    try
    {
        var userInfo = await GetCurrentUser();
        if (userInfo.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _currentUser.UserName) }.Concat(_currentUser.Claims.Select(c => new Claim(c.Key, c.Value))).ToList();
            var roles = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role);
            claims.Remove(roles);
            var rolesString = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(roles.Value);
            foreach (var role in rolesString)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }
            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Server authentication");
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request failed:" + ex.ToString());
    }
    return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
}
```